# while using table valued parameter how to pass multiple parameter together to stored prcocedure

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table-valued parameter like this

CREATE TYPE dbo.Loc AS TABLE(Lo integer);

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary]  
                        @startDate datetime,  
                        @endDate datetime,
                        @locations dbo.Loc readonly
              ..........................
              ...........................
WHERE     (Transaction_tbl.dtime BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate) 
AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (select Lo from @locations))
```

I have a listbox that contains multiple items. I can select multiple items from my listbox. How can I pass multiple Locationid to my stored procedure

```
 cnt = LSTlocations.SelectedItems.Count
 If cnt > 0 Then
          For i = 0 To cnt - 1
        Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
        locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
next
end if  


  Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            Dim cmd23 As New SqlCommand("IBS_TransactionSummary", con.connect)
            cmd23.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd23.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = startdate
            cmd23.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = enddate
Dim tvp1 As SqlParameter =cmd23.Parameters.Add("@location", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
 tvp1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
        tvp1.TypeName = "dbo.Loc"
     da.SelectCommand = cmd23
    da.Fill(ds)
```

but i am getting error..i am working on windows forms in vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some examples of how to do this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (see the section titled "Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Stored Procedure
").

The simplest thing would seem to be filling a `DataTable` with the values the user selected and passing that to the stored procedure for the `@locations` parameter.

Perhaps something along the lines of (note I don't have VB.NET installed, so treat this as an outline of how it should work, not necessarily as code that will work straight away):

```
cnt = LSTlocations.SelectedItems.Count
' *** Set up the DataTable here: *** '
Dim locTable As New DataTable
locTable.Columns.Add("Lo", GetType(Integer))

If cnt > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To cnt - 1
        Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
        locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
        ' *** Add the ID to the table here: *** '
        locTable.Rows.Add(locid)
    next
end if  

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim cmd23 As New SqlCommand("IBS_TransactionSummary", con.connect)
cmd23.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = startdate
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = enddate
' *** Supply the DataTable as a parameter to the procedure here: *** '
Dim tvp1 As SqlParameter =cmd23.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", locTable)
tvp1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
tvp1.TypeName = "dbo.Loc"
da.SelectCommand = cmd23
da.Fill(ds)
```

Comment: at this line:locTable.Rows.Add(row) i am getting error:Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.Int32[]> in Lo Column.  Expected type is Int32.

Comment: Updated - try `locTable.Rows.Add(locid)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir...now working fine...i shall be very thank full to you

Answer (score 0):

[Table types SQL SERVER 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

if you version of sql server > = 2008.

Answer (score 0):

```
cnt = LSTlocations.SelectedItems.Count
' *** Set up the DataTable here: *** '
Dim locTable As New DataTable
locTable.Columns.Add("Lo", GetType(Integer))

If cnt > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To cnt - 1
        Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
        locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
        ' *** Add the ID to the table here: *** '
        locTable.Rows.Add(locid)
    next
end if  

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim cmd23 As New SqlCommand("IBS_TransactionSummary", con.connect)
cmd23.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = startdate
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = enddate
' *** Supply the DataTable as a parameter to the procedure here: *** '
Dim tvp1 As SqlParameter =cmd23.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", locTable)
tvp1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
tvp1.TypeName = "dbo.Loc"
da.SelectCommand = cmd23
da.Fill(ds)
```